# Protractor: Enable native events in Firefox on linux

Tags: firefox, protractor

I'm trying to turn of the Firefox native events on Linux. I tried to set the following in my protractor.conf.js file:

```
capabilities: {
  browserName: 'firefox'
  nativeEvents: true
}
.....
```

But it doesn't seem to work at all. This capability looks like a correct one because if I substitute its value to 'true' instead of true, the underlying WebDriver throws ClassCastExceptio: cannot cast String to Boolean.

I also tried to manually create the firefox profile (as described [here](https://github.com/juliemr/protractor-demo/tree/master/howtos/setFirefoxProfile)) but still no luck.

Idea how to enable the native events in Firefox on Linux?